# Fragmento de codigo static

Tags: java, c#

Estoy traduciendo un código de Java a C# y me encontré con este fragmento de código:

```
static
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        TABLE_T[i] = (int) (long) ((1L << 32) * Math.abs(Math.sin(i + 1)));
}
```

Por lo que leí, java permite definir como static fragmentos de código, pero no encuentro una manera de pasar este código a C#.

Si alguien me pudiera orientar, se lo agradecería demasiado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static { ... }` es llamado [`inicializador estatico`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) en java. Es el codigo que se ejecuta solo una vez en todo el programa cuando se accede por primera vez a un miembro estático de la clase.

En [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) es llamado [`constructor estatico`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors). Esto se hace creando un constructor con el nombre de clase pero agregando `static` a la asignatura y eliminando cualquier modificador de visibilidad:

```
public class MyClase{

    // constructor estatico. Se ejecuta una sola vez, al momento de acceder a una propiedad static
   static MyClase()
   {
      // codigo
   }
}
```

Comment: Por puntualizar, la parte estática de Java se ejecuta al ser cargada la clase por su ClassLoader. Un simple `Class.forName("MyClase");`  podría lanzar la ejecución.

Comment: Me fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta. Concisa y directo al grano. Muchas gracias.

Comment: muy parecido a c# por cierto.

Answer (score 0):

encontre esta respuesta con algo de informacion de que es el bloque estatico :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java

Se trata de un constructor que se ejecutara con la definicion de tus propiedades estaticas y se ejecutara incluso antes de crear la instancia de tu objeto (afecta a toda la clase, no solo al objeto)

Comment: es exactamente al reves..

Comment: ohhh, un iniciador de las propiedades estaticas... hoy he aprendido algo nuevo !

Comment: Ahora la respuesta paso a ser mala, porque es solo un link. o explicas algo, o va a terminar reportada como de baja calidad